# Firebase Cloud Messaging com $cordovaPush, como funcionar também para iPhone?

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, ionic2, angular, cordova-plugin

Estou emulando meu aplicativo pelo Intel XDK para o IOS. Utilizo ele, por trabalhar com Windows e ele emula e dá as mensagens de erro muito bem.

O primeiro erro, é que quando o usuário faz o login, ele pega o senderID do Cloud Messaging e faz o registro do GCM na minha base de dados para enviar as notificações de acordo com as regras do meu app.

No entanto, na linha 29, que é:

```
$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function (result) {
```

Obviamente dá um erro, porque não estou usando o Android, quero usar o iOS também. Como posso adaptar meu código para utilizar com o iOS também?

Segue o código completo:

```
$scope.register_gcm = function () {

            $ionicLoading.show();
            var androidConfig = {
                "senderID": "MEU_ID_DO_GOOGLE_MESSAGE",

            };


            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                //            alert("device ready");
                $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function (result) {
                    // Success
                }, function (err) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                })

                $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
                    //                 alert("Passa do rootScope.on");
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    switch (notification.event) {
                        case 'registered':
                            if (notification.regid.length > 0) {
                                console.log(notification.regid);

                          //      alert(notification.regid);

                                $http.get("http://MEUSITE_ONDE_FACO_UPDATE_NA_TABELA_DE_USUARIO.com.br/admin/apis/push_config_vovo/set_gcmkey.php?user_id=" + window.localStorage.getItem("user_id") + "&gcm_key=" + notification.regid)
                                    .then(function (result) {
                                        console.log("printo the result.data: " + result.data);
                                //        alert(result.data);
                                        window.localStorage.setItem("gcm", notification.regid);
                                //        alert("GCM REGISTERED!!");
                                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                                    }, function (result) {
                                        console.log(result);
                                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                                    })



                            }
                            break;

                        case 'message':
                            // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                            //alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
                            break;

                        case 'Erro':
                            alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
                            break;

                        default:
                            alert('Nenhum evento GCM foi encontrado');
                            break;
                    }
                });

            }, false);


        }
```

Funciona muito bem para o Android, mas como fazer para funcionar também no IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você precisa passar as configurações de acordo com a plataforma. Sendo assim você precisa verificar se é IOS/Android e em seguida passar os parâmetros para o $cordovaPush.register. Pra isso você pode usar o https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html.

```
  // CONFIGS
  var pushConfig = {
    android: {
      "senderID": "ID_GOOGLE",
    }, 
    ios: {
      "senderID": "ID_IOS",
    }
  };

  // SELECIONAR CONFIG DE ACORDO COM PLATFORM
  function getPushConfig() {
    return pushConfig[device.platform.toLowerCase()];
  }

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
      $cordovaPush.register(getPushConfig()).then(function (result) {
```